# BreezeJS - clear metadata and cache

Tags: breeze

In my client solution there is a need to do a partial refresh from the server. Is it possible to clear all the defined constructors and all the cache?

even tried

```
 dataService = new breeze.DataService(breezeDataServiceSettings),
        ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();
        manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService , metadataStore: ms});
```

on every refresh

i found that i need to clear yhe entityType in the prototype

```
var ctor = ctorFactory.createCtor(allTypes[type].shortName),
                store = manager.metadataStore;

            ctor.prototype.entityType = undefined; 
            store.registerEntityTypeCtor(allTypes[type].shortName, ctor);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually,  `new breeze.EntityManager(...)` **always** produces a clean manager with an empty `metadataStore`. Look at the network traffic and you'll see that a new manager requests metadata from the server on its first query.

You have to *want to avoid* that squeaky clean behavior ... and I usually do want to avoid that behavior.

Usually, if I've acquired the metadata once and initialized my manager with it, I want to create new managers that are set up in the same way. And you can:

```
// manager2 has manager1's settings but not its cache contents
var manager2 = manager1.createEmptyCopy();
```

But I guess in your case you desire the default.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
var controllerName = '...',
    serviceUrl = 'https://..../' + controllerName,
    metadataUrl = serviceUrl + '/Metadata',
    entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager();
$.ajax({ url: metadataUrl, type: 'GET', dataType: 'text' })
    .then(metadataJson => {
        entityManager.metadataStore.importMetadata(metadataJson);
        entityManager.metadataStore.addDataService(new breeze.DataService({ serviceName: serviceUrl }));
    });
```